# the downloaded file is not saving in given location

Tags: c, libcurl

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://localhost/aaa.txt";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\bbb.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some one has posted this code for a question. But on execution of this file the downloaded file is not saving in C drive rather a new txt file will be generating with name "C:\cat.txt"... I want the downloaded file will be stored in my desired location in hard drive.. can any one help me...

Comment: Please use code block feature to insert code otherwise it will be hard to read and find errors..this also fades the viewer's interest in the question.

Comment: @ryanlancer The Code Block is                                        char *url = "http://localhost/aaa.txt";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\bbb.txt"; ----> Problem Comes Here

Answer (score 0):

First, the default `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` accepts a `FILE *` and uses `fwrite` using whatever's been set with `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`, so you don't need to override the function unless you're using curl as a Win32 DLL.

Also, you aren't checking the return from `fopen`, which may fail.

I suspect in this case that you either aren't recompiling your code, or are running a different binary from the one you built